# Widget not showing up android

Tags: android, android-widget

I am trying to create a widget for my application,
I implemented widget using

```
File->New->widget->Appwidget
```

all the corresponding code was auto-generated, 
but when I run my app, the widget is not shown, can anyone help me on how do I show the widget on my home screen.

my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.work.income">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AddExpenseActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".AddIncomeActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login" />

    <receiver android:name=".NewAppWidget"
      >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"

            android:resource="@xml/new_app_widget_info" />
    </receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you checked in your home screen -> widgets ?

Comment: @AndersKink yes I checked, not showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working fine.

The thing that helped me was rebooting my phone, after that the widget started appearing in the widget list.

refer [Widget not showing in widget list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237902/widget-not-showing-in-widget-list)

refer this to get widget on the homescreen [How to add a widget to the Android home screen from my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100926/how-to-add-a-widget-to-the-android-home-screen-from-my-app)

Answer (score 2):

hi please check that code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.sairamkrishna.myapplication" >

   <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
      <receiver android:name=".MainActivity">

      <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"></action>
      </intent-filter>

      <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
         android:resource="@xml/mywidget"></meta-data>

      </receiver>

   </application>
</manifest>
```

In your code there is one default launcher but when you create a widget no need to launcher

Comment: I am still confused, can you please educate me on this issue, My launcher activity in "LoginActivity" so where should I make the change

Comment: how do I trigger the widget so as to show it on my homescreen

Comment: i am fully help you on this topic and project  also my english is not good

Comment: its ok. i only want my issue to get solved, please help me

Comment: can you explain the working of your project i mean what is the flow of your project